# Exception handling in code layers in java

Tags: java, exception

I have two layers in my project say A & B. Layer A functions throw set of exceptions Ae1, Ae2, Ae3. Layer B functions throw exceptions Be1, Be2,Be3, Be4. Layer B functions are called from different functions in Layer A.

A function in layer A can throws more than one exception. Similarly in layer B.

Also, I have a mapping like whenever I get exceptions Be1 and Be2 from Layer B functions, I **catch** those exceptions inside layer A function definition using try catch and throw it as Ae3. Similarly, exceptions Be3 is thrown as Ae2, and Be4 is thrown as Ae1.

```
public void function1InLayerB throws Be1, Be2, Be4{
    ......
}
```

Now what I am doing is :

```
public void function1InLayerA throws Ae3, Ae1{
    try{
         function1InLayerB();
    } catch(Be1){
         throw new Ae3;
    } catch(Be2){
         throw new Ae3;
    } catch(Be4){
         throw new Ae1;
    }   
}
```

So, I want to **avoid such a lot of try catch blocks**, by using a function  or any other different approach and have function in layer A simple as

```
public void fnuction1InLayerA throws Ae1, A2{
   ....
   new_function(function1InLayerB());
}
```

Is it possible to write a common function like this ?

Note : Java version 6.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 you can do this:

```
    try{
         function1InLayerB();
    } catch(Be1 | Be2){
         throw new Ae3;
    } catch(Be4){
         throw new Ae1;
    }
```

Thus you avoid repetition when the common exception happens in catch blocks.

For Java 6 and less:

```
try{
    function1InLayerB();
}catch(Exception ex){
    manageExceptions(ex);
}
```

And create a method that checks the instance of the exception to manage it and throw the desired exception.

```
private void manageExceptions(Exception ex){

    if(ex instanceOf Be1 || ex instanceOf Be2){
        throw new Ae3;
    }else if(ex instance of Be4){
        throw new Ae1;
    }...
    else
        throw new Exception(ex); 

}
```

Comment: the project is on a java version less than 7